# Ignore quotes from CSV file while loading it into HIVE table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a csv file which has data in below format:

```
"SomeName1",25,"SomeString1"
"SomeName2",26,"SomeString2"
"SomeName3",27,"SomeString3"
```

I am loading this CSV into a hive table. In the table, column 1 and 3 get inserted together with the quotes which I do not want. I want column 1 to be `SomeName1` and column 3 to be `SomeString1`

I have tried with

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)
```

but it does not work and keeps the "".

What should be the approach here?

Table creation statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `abcdefgh`(
  `name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `age` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `value` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'quoteChar'='\"',
  'separatorChar'='\t')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://a-b-c-d-e:9000/user/hive/warehouse/abcdefgh'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'numFiles'='1',
  'numRows'='0',
  'rawDataSize'='0',
  'totalSize'='3134916',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1490713221')
```

Comment: Which SERDE are you using ? Please post the complete table creation query

Comment: ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'

Comment: CREATE TABLE `abcdefgh`(
  `name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `age` string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
  `value` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'quoteChar'='\"',
  'separatorChar'='\t')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://a-b-c-d-e:9000/user/hive/warehouse/abcdefgh'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'numFiles'='1',
  'numRows'='0',
  'rawDataSize'='0',
  ,)

Comment: It would be better to edit your question instead of writing in the comment section, it isn't readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your delimiter should be a comma: `"separatorChar" = ','`

```
create external table mytable 
(
    col1 string
   ,col2 int
   ,col3 string
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties 
(
    "separatorChar" = ','
   ,"quoteChar"     = '"'
)  
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| mytable.col1 | mytable.col2 | mytable.col3 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| SomeName1    |           25 | SomeString1  |
| SomeName2    |           26 | SomeString2  |
| SomeName3    |           27 | SomeString3  |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!!